# Function on $\mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}$ with small Fourier transform?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, characters

For $f:\mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{C}$, define the Fourier transform $\widehat{f}:\mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{C}$ in the usual way, viz., $\widehat{f}(\xi) = \sum_x f(x) e(-\xi x/p^k)$, where $e(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$. What is an example of a function $f:\mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}\to \{-1,1\}$ such that $|\widehat{f}(\xi)|\ll p^{k/2}$ for all $\xi$?

For $k=1$, there are lots of choices: we can let $f(\xi) = \left(\frac{\xi}{p}\right)$ for $\xi\ne 0$, and $f(\xi) = 1$ (say) for $\xi = 0$, but other things (such as $f(\xi) = \left(\frac{\xi^3 + a \xi + b}{p}\right)$, or other algebraic-geometrical choices) also work.

What I want is an explicit construction (preferrably one that is as "clean" as possible) for $k>1$. Existence is not hard.

Comment: Does $x$ run over $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z$ in $\hat f(\xi)$? And do you really mean $e(-\xi x/p)$, or should it be $e(-\xi x/p^k)$, with $x$ running over $\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z$?

Comment: A construction based on Rudin-Shapiro polynomials should work, see the introduction to Flat Littlewood polynomials exist by Paul Balister, Bela Bollobas, Robert Morris, Julian Sahasrabudhe and Marius Tiba. By the way, why is "existence not hard"? A random construction would miss by a log factor.

Comment: I meant $p^k$ in the denominator - thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment Harald. If one uses the results of Balister https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.08777 then you can take $n = p^k$ and this will give an example; the exponential sum is actually uniformly small at all $\theta$, not just $\theta = r/p^k$. I'll have to think whether there is an example that is more natural as regards the $p$-structure on $\mathbf{Z}/p^k \mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: @BenGreen I was replying to Joe Silverman, sorry. Thanks for the reference. On "existence is not hard" - perhaps, instead of "not hard" I should have said "immediate, given a standard result that I did not know about until a couple of days ago, when Martin Kassabov told me about it" - I mean J. Spencer, "Six standard deviations suffice", TAMS v289 n 2 (1986). You are right that the obvious probabilistic approach would miss by a $\log$ factor. Also, thanks to Martin K. for the question, which is really his!

Comment: I see, yes indeed it follows immediately (but not explicitly) from the Spencer result.

Comment: Right. Here is the link: https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1985-289-02/S0002-9947-1985-0784009-0/S0002-9947-1985-0784009-0.pdf

Comment: Martin just told me that he learned about this question from Afonso Bandeira (ETHZ).

Comment: Does the Rudin Shapiro polynomial construction (which is explicit though maybe not "algebraic") answer your original question?

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler answer, but technically it does.